# How do you get "some Text" from <abc>some Text</abc> with python?

Tags: python, xml, dom

I'm using python & mindom module.

I'd like to extract `abc` from

```
<someTag>abc</someTag>.
```

Suppose I can get to `someTag`, how do I retrieve the `abc` from there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
>>> from xml.dom.minidom import parseString
>>> x = parseString('<abc>foo</abc>')
>>> x.getElementsByTagName('abc')[0].firstChild.nodeValue
u'foo'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have the someTag
you can get it's data by calling tag.data

f.ex. by

```
from xml.dom.minidom import parseString
dom =  parseString("<someTag>abc</someTag>")
tag = dom.getElementsByTagName("someTag")[0]
node = tag.childNodes[0]
print node.data
```

for a more worked out example, see http://docs.python.org/library/xml.dom.minidom.html#dom-example